# How to use custom GraphQLScalarType with default GraphQL types?

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I created a GraphQLScalarType to prevent arguments with empty strings. The issue however is if I don't pass the argument at all when calling the mutation, the mutation succeeds and gives the field a value of null.

Usually, I'd wrap the type in a GraphQLNonNull type e.g
`GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)`. But that doesn't work with my custom scalar type.

```js
function validateEmptyStrings(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError('Value must be a string')
    }
    if (value === "") {
        throw new TypeError('Value cannot be empty')
    }
    return value
}

const NonEmptyString = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'NonEmptyString',
    serialize: validateEmptyStrings,
    parseValue: validateEmptyStrings,
})
```

My mutation below

```js
addClient: {
      type: ClientType,
      args: {
        name: {type: NonEmptyString, required: true},
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        const client = new Client ({
          name: args.name,
        })
        return client.save()
     }
}
```

Wrapping the arg 'name' type like `GraphQLNonNull(NonEmptyString)` doesn't work, and neither does the `required: true` do anything

Comment: Is there a specific error you get when trying to create the GraphQLNonNull wrapped type?

Comment: The error message was "Expected value of type \"NonEmptyString!\", found \"\"; Value cannot be empty" 
Which apparently is exactly what I'm looking for, dunno how I missed that.

Thanks, Matthew

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Wrapping the arg 'name' type like GraphQLNonNull(NonEmptyString) does indeed work.

I'm not sure how I skipped that part. Thanks Matthew Herbst for making me take a second look